# why is my flask app not connecting to the right room

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I was trying to make a multiroom app with flask and flask socket-io integration but i think something is offset as if I try to join another room on another tab it sends the info to all rooms and other rooms show someone has joined in that room and after that if I send message it also don't work.
here's my code

````
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room
from colorama import Fore, Style

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/chat")
def chat():
    username = request.args.get("username")
    room = request.args.get("room")

    if username and room:
        return render_template("chat.html", username=username, room=room)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("home"))

@socketio.on('join_room')
def handle_join_room(data):
    info = "[INFO] "+f"[ROOM: {data['room']}]: "+f"User {data['username']} has joined"
    print(Fore.CYAN+info)
    join_room(data['room'])
    socketio.emit('join_room_ann', data)

    Style.RESET_ALL

@socketio.on('send_mess')
def handle_mess(data):
    info = f"[MESSAGE][ROOM: {data['room']}][USER:{data['username']}]: {data['message']}"
    print(info)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)}```


and html side
client
[{% extends "common.html" %}
{% block index %}
<div class="log left">
    <p>Username:</p>
    
    <p class="cls">{{username}}</p>
    
    <p>Room:</p>
    
    <p class="cls">{{room}}</p>
</div>
    <div id="messages" class='bottoml log'>
        <p>in room:</p>
    </div>

<form action="" id="inp_form">
    <div class="log chat">
        <div class="in">
            <input type="text" id="inp_box" class="chat_in" placeholder="Type your text">
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
{% block chat %}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:5000");
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit("join_room",{
            username:"{{username}}",
            room:"{{room}}"
        });
        let inp_box = document.getElementById('inp_box');
        document.getElementById('inp_form').onsubmit = function (e){
            e.preventDefault();
            mes = inp_box.value.trim();
            if (mes.length){
                socket.emit('send_mess', {
                    username:"{{username}}",
                    room:"{{room}}",
                    message:mess
                })
            }
            inp_box.value='';
            inp_box.focus();
        }
    });
    socket.on('join_room_ann', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        const newnode = document.createElement('div');
        newnode.innerHTML = `${data.username}`;
        newnode.className+="newn"
        document.getElementById('messages').appendChild(newnode);
    })
</script>
{% endblock %}]
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the join room announcement just to the room in question, you have to indicate that in the `emit` call:

```
socketio.emit('join_room_ann', data, room=data['room'])
```

Without the `room` argument, the emit goes to all connected clients, regardless of what room they're in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was looking in the syntax of emit and found that we can also give a specific room so I tried this and it really worked.